# Creating a join using a link table and the Entity Framework

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc-3, linq

Right now I am struggling with ASP.Net and MVC3 to display a person.
I have a table with the person information, a table for type of person.
A person can be multiple types.
So I created a link table that links the personid and typeid.
I am struggling to find a way to p[ush both the user details and the different types they are part of.

So the ActionResult is taking a PersonID and I can display the person information just fine, but I also need to pass a list of the types they are part of.

Any help, examples or links to a tutorial would be great. Thanks in advance.

Here is what I have right now in my controller.

```
public ViewResult Details(long id)
    {
        champion champion = _db.champions.Single(c => c.id == id);
        return View(champion);
    }
```

I tried using a ViewBag object and a join statement but it got too complex and went beyond my knowledge of linq statements.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb738708.aspx

```
var champion = _db.champions.Include("TheOtherModel").SingleOrDefault(c => c.id == id);
return View(champion);
```

and you should've access to "TheOtherModel" by using

```
champion.TheOtherModel
```

or in your view:

```
@foreach (var item in Model.TheOtherModel){
    item.Property1
    ....
 }
```

(should contain a list).